# Working with django form templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to use templates (simple one) for reset password using Django Forms and Templates. Following are the files used:

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class ResetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    new_password = forms.CharField(
        label='New password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False),
    )
    confirm_new_password = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirm New password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False),
    )

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('password')

def clean(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['new_password']
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_new_password']
    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Passwords are not equal')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

`reset_password.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reset Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="reset_password_form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ reset_password_form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset Password" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In `views.py` am calling this page by

```
return render(request, "reset_password.html",
              {'form': reset_password_form})
```

and the output shows only a button of `Reset Password`, other two password fields are not shown. Can someone point any mistake or any way?

Comment: can you change `{{ reset_password_form.as_p }}` to  `{{ form.as_p}}`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `reset_password_form` in the variable `form`.So to render on template

Change

```
{{ reset_password_form.as_p }}
```

to

```
{{ form.as_p}}
```

**OR**

Change `{'form': reset_password_form}` to `{'reset_password_form': reset_password_form}`

Comment: print `reset_password_form` in `view` before render in html.Also paste view code in your question.

Comment: I changed the html page as u suggested --> `{{ form.as_p }}` and it works! Thanks